# Change connection on multiple .UNX universes

Tags: business-objects

I have approximately 80 .UNX universes for which I need to change the connection. They all have the same current connection and I want to update them all to the same new connection.

The only way I can figure out to do this is to retrieve each one individually from the repository within the Information Design Tool, change the connection, and then publish it right back to the repository.

Is that the only way? Is there any way to retrieve and/or publish multiple universes in a batch? I was able to do this in the Universe Design Tool with .UNV universes.

Thanks,

Noel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the existing connection in IDT and change the details.